# connecting a checkbox signal to a method in qt widget

Tags: c++, qt, widget

For example I have a three files
the generalsetting.ui, generalsetting.h, generalsetting.cpp .

I want to  trigger the enableNotification method when the Notifycheckbox in the UI file is clicked.
by passing the return value of the checkbox to the function

I tried using

```
connect(ui->notifyCheckBox, &QCheckBox::toggled, this, enableNotification(&QCheckBox::toggled));
```

and

```
connect(ui->notifyCheckBox, &QCheckBox::isChecked, this, enableNotification(&QCheckBox::toggled));
```

it does not work

here is the both the header and source

```
namespace Ui {
class GeneralSettings;
}

class GeneralSettings : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GeneralSettings(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~GeneralSettings() override;

private slots:
    void enableNotification(bool enable);

private:
    Ui::GeneralSettings *ui;
    Utils *utils;
};
```

the source File

```
GeneralSettings::GeneralSettings(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::GeneralSettings)
{
    ui->setupUi(this); 
    //here is where i am adding the connect function.
}

void GeneralSettings::enableNotification(bool enable)
{
    utils->settings->setValue("General/notify", enable);
}
```

PS:i included only the ones that i feel are useful

Comment: `enableNotification(&QCheckBox::toggled)` should probably be `&GeneralSettings::enableNotification` .  If that doesn't solve it then you really need to clarify what you mean by `"it does not work"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can connect to a lambda:

```
connect(ui->yyy, &QCheckBox::toggled, [this]()
    {
        qDebug() << "sd.." << ui->yyy->isChecked();
        enableNotification(ui->yyy->isChecked());
    });
```

or directly, same way as the signal

```
connect(ui->yyy, &QCheckBox::toggled,this, &Foo::enableNotification);
```